# Input moves up when keyboard appears

Tags: react-native, expo

Already tried different styles but the problem it's always here (at least on android).
I want the input position fixed, but when we focus (keyboard appear) and the input just goes up.

[Before Focus (It's OKAY)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yCRK.png)

[When we Focus (NOT OKAY)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIUYR.png)

input code:

```
<TextInput                            
            placeholder="Procurar Lazer..."                    
            style={[stylesListagem.inputBarFilter, {display:"flex"}]}
            onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
            value={value}
 />
```

InputStyle:

```
 inputBarFilter:{                
    height:40,
    width:250,                   
    borderRadius:100,     
    display:"none",   
    opacity:10,                   
},
```

ViewStyle where Input is:

```
viewSearchFilter:{
    position:"absolute",
    top:"14%",
    alignSelf:"center",            
    borderRadius:10,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',   
    opacity:50,     
},
```

Comment: please post value of stylesListagem.inputBarFilter object

Comment: I agree with @VáclavRyska

Comment: My bad! Already edited @VáclavRyska

Comment: try change `top:"14%",` to absolute value, because the height of the screen changes when keyboard is active

Comment: @VáclavRyska it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! The problem was on ViewStyle where Top:"14%", just changed to absolute value.